# Shorten long if else to get element from array based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, indexing

I have an array of seven values, which might or might not get extended. Then I have a variable `foo` which is between 1 and -1. Based on `foo`, I select one element of my array, but I'm not really happy with the current solution.

Is there a preferred way of doing so?

Example:

```
// Of course there's useful data in no order like the alphabet
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var foo = myFunc();  // Changes often between about 1 and -1
var index;

if (foo >= 0.1) {
    index = 6;
} else if (foo < 0.1 && foo >= 0.0) {
    index = 5;
} else if (foo < 0.0 && foo >= -0.1) {
    index = 4;
} else if (foo < -0.1 && foo >= -0.2) {
    index = 3;
} else if (foo < -0.2 && foo >= -0.3) {
    index = 2;
} else if (foo < -0.3 && foo >= -0.4) {
    index = 1;
} else {
    index = 0;
}

var element = myArray[index];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array and [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for getting the wanted number.

```js
const getIndex = v => [-0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, Infinity].findIndex(a => v < a);

console.log(getIndex(-0.5)); // 0
console.log(getIndex(-0.4)); // 1
console.log(getIndex(-0.3)); // 2
console.log(getIndex(-0.2)); // 3
console.log(getIndex(-0.1)); // 4
console.log(getIndex(0));    // 5
console.log(getIndex(0.1));  // 6
console.log(getIndex(0.2));  // 6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sorry for responding late, but I've tested it and could make my other code even smaller! This is _huge_! :)

Answer (score 3):

There would be lots of ways of doing this, but a simple one could be:

```
index = Math.floor(10 * (0.5 + foo));
if(index > 6)   index = 6;
if(index < 0)   index = 0;
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, there is no `int` and no typecasting. Use `Math.floor`

Comment: Too quick Bergi :-)

Comment: Awesome, even though not as readable as the other solution. Simply using clamping is great idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:
Some comparison are not necessary, here is a simpler version:

```
if (foo >= 0.1) {
    index = 6;
} else if (foo >= 0.0) {
    index = 5;
} else if (foo >= -0.1) {
    index = 4;
} else if (foo >= -0.2) {
    index = 3;
} else if (foo >= -0.3) {
    index = 2;
} else if (foo >= -0.4) {
    index = 1;
} else {
    index = 0;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
double pos[6] = {0.1, 0.0, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4};
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   if (foo >= pos[i]) {
       index = 6 - i;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: please note the question is tagged with `javascript` :-)

Comment: I like the 2nd solution, even though its C or the like :)
Let me try!

Comment: Ok, this is dead simple and easily extendable! (using `i < myArray.length`)
Thank you!